# How can I install vnstat on Amazon EC2 with Standard image?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, yum, apt-get

How can I install vnstat on Amazon EC2 with Standard image?

```
[ec2-user@ip-XXXXXXXXXX ~]$ sudo yum  install vnstat
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
No package vnstat available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by standard image i guess you mean the Amazon Linux AMI. Should install with:

```
sudo yum --enablerepo=epel install vnstat
```